# Preferred method for text shadow in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

I have created a Mac app and need to place a shadow behind the white letters to better differentiate the text from the background.  I noticed that I can use the "View Effects Inspector" in Interface Builder to add a drop shadow to static text.  Is this the preferred method of doing this?  I've seen examples of implementing by code but is it fine to use the Interface Builder approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a "preferred" method. The interface builder method works well and I personally haven't had any issues with it. You could take the code route and use `NSShadowAttributeName` (See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167) doc for more) to add a shadow to an `NSAttributedString`. In the end, either way you choose shouldn't matter.